# Loading HTML snippets with yepnope/modernizr.load()

Tags: jquery, modernizr, yepnope

I have a sequence of JS and CSS files that are being loaded and injected in a page with the modernizr.load() function (this is yepnope.js). But I want to load a few HTML snippets also, put them in script-tags and use them later on in my javasscript code.

The HTML snippets are located on a remote server (for example: domain.com/template/default/tweetlist), but when I load this file it is immediately executed, resulting in an error. I can disable this execution (by adding !noexec before the URL) and this stops the errors, but I don't know where the contents go. The callback doesn't return the response body.

```
scriptArray.push({
    load: "noexec!domain.com/template/default/"+widgetType,
    callback: function (url, result) {
        console.log("Template loaded!");
        // code to handle response body should go here
    }
})
```

This is the code I had so far and I am now stuck on that commentline (5).

Btw: This is not a crossdomain problem. The content gets loaded and the errors when noexec is disabled proove this.

Comment: +1 I can't find it... But what i did find is your pastebin paste :P http://pastebin.com/5GsadhTJ

Answer (score 0):

I found a sollution/hack for my problem. I wrapped the contents of the template file in javascript so the Modernizt script wouldn't throw an error and that new var is available in the callback.

This is (part of) the PHP file:

```
$template = file_get_contents($requestFilepath);
$template = str_replace("\r","",$template);
$template = str_replace("\n","",$template);
$template = str_replace("\t","",$template);
$template = str_replace("\r\n","",$template);
$template = str_replace("\"","'",$template);

echo 'var template = "'.$template.'"';
```

And this is the Javascript part:

```
$("body").append('<script type="text/html" id="tpl_'+templateName+'">'+template+'</script>');
```